# CI4 - Can't connect to a custom database

Tags: model, database-connection, codeigniter-4

I don't understand.
I'm trying to use a model with a custom database connection (https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html#accessing-models)...but CI4 doesn't take it.
CI4 is only considering the defaultDB set in Config/Database.

My custom connection is ok, it is sure.
Direct queries work fine. The problem appears only if I call my model class.

My controller script:

```
                $custom = [
                    'DSN'      => '',
                    'hostname' => 'myhostname',
                    'username' => 'myusername',
                    'password' => 'mypassword',
                    'database' => 'mydatabase',
                    'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
                    'DBPrefix' => '',
                    'pConnect' => false,
                    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
                    'charset'  => 'utf8',
                    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
                    'swapPre'  => '',
                    'encrypt'  => false,
                    'compress' => false,
                    'strictOn' => false,
                    'failover' => [],
                    'port'     => 3306,
                ];
                
                $db = \Config\Database::connect($custom);
                
                
                $basedd=model('App\Models\Users',true, $db);
                print_r($basedd->findAll());
```

My model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    public $primaryKey;
    protected $allowedFields;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->primaryKey='id';
    }
}
```

It returns:

*mysqli_sql_exception #1146
Table 'mydefaultdb.users' doesn't exist*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're changing the construct in your model.

Change your model to:

```
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields;
}
```

If you check the base code for the codeigniter model construct $db should be the first param and validation the second. You're removing both in your construct.

```
 public function __construct(?ConnectionInterface $db = null, ?ValidationInterface $validation = null)
 {
        /**
         * @var BaseConnection|null $db
         */
        $db ??= Database::connect($this->DBGroup);

        $this->db = $db;

        parent::__construct($validation);
 }
```

**Never** change the construct structure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you're right concerning the construct structure.

Unfortunately, il doesn't change anything to the problem.
I have exactly the same issue when I remove my constructor...

Comment: Ok, I've got something...in fact I have a sub class between,the base code and my model...
First of all, you're right: the construct parameters are not transmitted to CI4 model class.

I'm working on it...

Answer (score 0):

It's ok ;-)
I've just had to insert the parent construct in my subclass, and in my model...and preserve the variable transmission each time:

```
function __construct($var1, $var2, etc.)
    {
        parent::__construct($var1, $var2, etc.);
    ...other commands
    }
```

It was important for me to keep a constructor in my models, because I have a complex CRUD.
I've had present a simple code to make me understand, but the real one is much more complicated.

Thx ;-)